Human only walk straightly and looks like zombie plague but not looks like that, and the women with the little girl is the main character to survive
I can't identify this movie, I've watching this movie when I was a child, I don't know what year it is, but as I know the film is not old yet.
A plague like disease has been spreading around the world, I don't know the accurate one. People affected with this just walk straightly but not freely. A woman "hair blonde" with a little girl was among 1/3 of human who were not affected with this disease. They survived to fight that disease.
Any human who does not walk straightly will be pursued by those who walk straightly. Therefore, those who doesn't like this must walk straightly like unaffected ones.
The language of the film is English language,
The origin is from USA, Hollywood I think.
Only that what I know, sorry for not explain it at first.

This sounds like the movie "The Invasion" starring Nicole Kidman. Nicole and her kid (its a boy though) walk among the infected people who walk around like zombies and have no feelings or expressions. To escape, the mother and the kid both pretend like the them devoid of human expressions.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invasion_(film)
It could also maybe be the 1993 film - Body Snatchers.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_Snatchers_(1993_film)

Wow thank you for your answer, your question is true, that's my film who I want watch it again, and make my childhood raise up again, thank you~

happy to help :)
